# ClickHouse output by columns, not by rows (transpose without transpose actually?)

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way to return data from ClickHouse not by rows but by columns?

So instead of result in a following form for columns `a` and `b`

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

I'd get a transposed result

| - | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |

The point is I want to access data per column, eg. iterate over everything in column `a`.

I was checking available output formats - Arrow would do but it is not supported by my platform for now.

I'm looking for a most effective way. E.g. considered ClickHouse stores data in columns already, it does not have to process it into rows so I can transfer it back to columns using array functions afterwards. I'm not familiar with internals very much but I was wondering that I could somehow skip transposing rows if data are already in columns.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is no easy way to do it.
And a bigger issue that it's against the SQL conception.

---

You can use native protocol, although you will get columns in blocks by 65k rows.

`col_a 65k values, col_b 65k values, col_a next 65k values, col_b next 65k values`

Comment: Hmm thanks for reply! Right. What do you mean by SQL conception here exactly? I stumbled upon `Native`  which seemed promising at first: `The most efficient format.` and then it was "umm" at the end: 
`You can use this format to quickly generate dumps that can only be read by the ClickHouse DBMS. It does not make sense to work with this format yourself.` Upvoted ofc.

Comment: Conception that number of columns, their names and types are known before query execution. And each Row has the same set of columns.